# How can I define a new stream by REST call on Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to define and deploy a new stream on spring cloud data flow using the REST API. But on [documentations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-index), there is no reference about how I need to structure my "POST" call.

When I send a POST call to http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions
with:

```
 {   "name": "chp",
    "dslText": "time | log", }
```

I get as answer:

```
  {
    "logref": "MissingServletRequestParameterException",
    "message": "Required String parameter 'name' is not present",
    "links": []
  }
```

Anyone knows what is the format to use REST API?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to make sure the relevant properties are included in the URL parameter with proper encoding.

For example, `ticktock` stream creation would be:

> curl -X POST  http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions\?definition\=time+%7C+log\&name\=foo

For example, `ticktock` stream deployment would be:

> curl -X POST  http://localhost:9393/streams/deployments/foo

Comment: Thank you so much, Sabby.

I just found another format easier to understand : 

curl -X POST -d "name=ticktock&definition=time | log" http://localhost:9393/streams/definitions?deploy=false

Comment: @Lucas: Cooler!